# How to call a file for picturebox

Tags: c#, windows, forms, picturebox

I have a Form  with 6 arrays, 15 elements each. I wrote them in a way that if I search for myself (being the 1st element in the string[] name array), the form would load the 1st element of every array: age, gender, hobby, photo etc. 
Here is the part of the pictureBox code I'm using

```
//I have more arrays here, like: Name,Gender,Age,Hobby,Place & Talent
string[] photo=new string[] { "764.jpg", " 765.jpg", " 766.jpg", " 767.jpg"," 765.jpg", " 767.jpg", " 768.jpg", " 769.jpg", " 770.jpg", " 771.jpg",  " 772.jpg", " 773.jpg", " 774.jpg", " 775.jpg", " 776.jpg"};

string name="",gender="",place="",warning=""; int age = 0; string image="";

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            if (textBox6.Text == emri[i])
                  {
                      //I applied every element of every array to the declared variables
                      image = photo[i];
                      j++;
                  }
            if (j == 1)
                  {
                       //Associated the textBoxes with the variables
                       pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\NComputers\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\Sony Xperia\" + image);

                  }
            else
                  { 
                       MessageBox.Show("Person not found!"); 
                  }
```

While there are no errors shown, the picture simply doesn't load. All the other items are working. Help?

Comment: How do you know there are no errors? Put the code in a try/catch block to verify.

Comment: You're pointing to your bin\Debug to look for your image, are you sure this is the correct path? Do you mean to be pointing in the same directory?

Comment: _Here is the part of the pictureBox code_ What event is that? Did you use the debugger?? You should always use the debugger before posting here!!! What are the findings there??

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I tried it but my program doesn't catch any

Comment: @wentimo Yes, that's how I saw it on another thread. I also went to Solution explorer, clicked "show all files", bin,Debug,Sony Xperia and included them to my project. I could try another path, but I doubt it would work

Comment: @TaW I meant that I have more codes in my form, but I just showed the codes which I believe might include the bug (I don't think I should post all of my code)

Comment: @TaW I did debug, and as I wrote in the main post, there are no errors. All of my textBoxes and richtextBoxes are working, but the picturebox stays empty like the code doesn't work. That's the problem

Comment: I haven't used picture boxes before but the examples I'm finding online set the height/width or set SizeMode to AutoSize. Is it possible you need to do this for the picture box to display properly?

Comment: I would try calling Update on the picture box and I would try hard coding a simple image path C:\764.jpg to narrow down the problem.

Comment: No, all you need is to set the image. Soemtimes, depending on from where you call the shown code (which we still don't know!!) you can add a pb.Refresh() - But the immediate question is: Does the dubugger hit the line??? (ictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile..)

Comment: TaW, Thank you for your trying to help me
But it seems @SteveWellens fixed my program. I moved it on C drive and now it works. But I am still puzzled why wouldn't another path work?
Thank y'all!

Comment: Any path you have access right to will work, provided you always set it correctly.